# Extend Life of a Temp Table in Redshift As Non Admin User

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I use temp tables to conduct complex analysis on massive datasets; however, the temp tables are auto dropped after 1-2 hours, and I often need longer.

As a read only user, is there a command that will reset the timer or add time without requesting a change from administrators?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no automatic clean-up of temp tables after some time.  Temp tables should last the length of the session or until explicitly dropped.  There is the normal commit/rollback rules that would apply to normal tables.

I suspect that your session is being dropped/reset.  There are a number of reasons that could happen but let's start with showing that it is or isn't happening.  Can you check your pid (session id) before and after this happens?  Is it the same or does it change?  You can even check after the fact to see if the pid of the temp table creating query (stl_query) is the same as the current pid.

The function you will need is - pg_backend_pid()

```
select pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: You are correct.  It was buried in the logs, but my session was reset - causing the table to drop.

Comment: So now to the question of 'why?'.  There are a number of timeouts that can do this as well as features of benches / connectors.  There is one subtle one to point out and that is network equipment timeouts.  AWS doesn't have these internally but if you are connecting from outside of AWS to Redshift it can be a problem.  "Idle" connections are often closed by routers to free up channels / ports.  A tunnel and keep-alive packets is the only solution I know of to resolve this case.